# Do I have to add it at the end of the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

> It's incredible how squirrels plant trees without even knowing (it).

Do I need that *it* at the end?

Comment: To my ear, the "it" is optional, especially in spoken English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sentence sounds bad without something after *knowing*, such as

how
(that) they do
it

This is because the sentence suggests that *know* is transitive here.  Or at least that it needs some kind of object to sound complete. It would be the same if it were *realizing*.

Answer (score 1):

To my ear, the "it" makes it flow better, especially with the use of "even" in your sentence. However, this convention is likely different from place to place. You don't need the "it", but to some English speakers it will sound more natural.